# Git authentication over apache_mod_krb

Tags: git, http, authentication, kerberos

I'm using git repo  with git-http-backend. In apache2 I have location what needs authentication for clone and push actions. When I protected it location with AuthType Basic
all works is fine, git passes authentication and can clone and push, but if I change type to KerberosV5 git can't access to repo with correctly credentials. If I'm using my browser I have access to location what to protect kerberos.

```
git clone http://user@mydomain.com/git/myapp.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/myapp/.git/
Password:
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing http://user@mydomain.com/git/myapp.git/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

and in apache error logs

```
[Fri Aug 06 17:15:50 2010] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1579): [client 192.168.12.153]  kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type KerberosV5 
[Fri Aug 06 17:15:50 2010] [debug] src/mod_auth_kerb.c(1579): [client 192.168.12.153]kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type KerberosV5
```

git-core 1:1.7.1-1~bpo50+1 apache2  2.2.9-10+lenny8
libapache2-mod-auth-kerb 5.3-5

Comment: I somehow doubt Git currently supports authenticating itself via Kerberos. Just to confirm, your client is running on Debian Lenny?

Comment: Yes client running in lenny. I know that git don't support authentication via Kerberos like SSO(with help ticket), but kerberos can emulate basic authentication in apache and this don't work.

Answer (score 3):

> Problem in curl, because git in debian was compiled with curl option `ANY_AUTH`, and when git client try connect to webserver and first ask it negotiate auth and it can't do it, git don't try basic auth.

That will be more robust, with Git 2.3.1 (Q1/Q2 2015): see [commit 4dbe664](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dbe66464b4fd695c5989cc272fa0edd6475037c) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204):

> #### `remote-curl`: fall back to `Basic` auth if `Negotiate` fails

> Apache servers using `mod_auth_kerb` can be configured to allow the user
> to authenticate either using Negotiate (using the Kerberos ticket) or
> Basic authentication (using the Kerberos password).  Often, one will
> want to use Negotiate authentication if it is available, but fall back
> to Basic authentication if the ticket is missing or expired.

> However, `libcurl` will try very hard to use something other than `Basic`
> auth, even over HTTPS.
> If `Basic` and something else are offered, `libcurl` will never attempt to use `Basic`, even if the other option fails.
> **Teach the HTTP client code to stop trying authentication mechanisms that
> don't use a password (currently `Negotiate`) after the first failure, since if they failed the first time, they will never succeed**.

---

> when git client try connect to webserver and first ask it negotiate auth and it can't do it, git don't try basic auth.

It will, <del>with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021)</del> (see second part below): before, when accessing a server with a URL like `https://user:pass@site/`, Git did not to fall back to the basic authentication with the credential material embedded in the URL after the "Negotiate" authentication failed.
<del>Now (Git 2.32), Git does</del> (not yet, but soon).

See [commit 1b0d954](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b0d9545bb85912a16b367229d414f55d140d3be) (22 Mar 2021) by [Christopher Schenk (`chschenk`)](https://github.com/chschenk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5013802](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501380286295cac300dae86c3f0f6c10ff34b767), 30 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b0d9545bb85912a16b367229d414f55d140d3be): fall back to basic auth if Negotiate fails
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christopher Schenk</sup>

> When the username and password are supplied in a url like this `https://myuser:secret@git.exampe/myrepo.git` and the server supports the negotiate authenticaten method, git does not fall back to basic auth and `libcurl` hardly tries to authenticate with the negotiate method.
>
> Stop using the Negotiate authentication method after the first failure because if it fails on the first try it will never succeed.

However, this is still in progress:

See [commit ecf7b12](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecf7b129fa8619bfe16c5f7e470717ad79186e07), [commit b694f1e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b694f1e49ec39f45f61ca3b6d9df5945cbf43b71) (18 May 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c69f2f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c69f2f8c869361e9e2bdb9fb3ceb2fe058013744), 21 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`Revert "remote-curl`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecf7b129fa8619bfe16c5f7e470717ad79186e07): fall back to basic auth if Negotiate fails"
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Ben Humphreys</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> This reverts [commit 1b0d954](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b0d9545bb85912a16b367229d414f55d140d3be) (`remote-curl`: fall back to basic auth if Negotiate fails, 2021-03-22, Git v2.32.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501380286295cac300dae86c3f0f6c10ff34b767) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a65ce7f831aa5fcc596c6d23fcde543d98b39bd7)).
>
> That commit does fix the situation it intended to (avoiding Negotiate even when the credentials were provided in the URL), but it creates a more serious regression: we now never hit the conditional for "we had a username and password, tried them, but the server still gave us a 401".
>
> That has two bad effects:
>
> 1. we never call `credential_reject()`, and thus a bogus credential stored by a helper will live on forever
> 2. we never return `HTTP_NOAUTH,` so the error message the user gets is "`The requested URL returned error: 401`", instead of "`Authentication failed`".
>
> Doing this correctly seems non-trivial, as we don't know whether the Negotiate auth was a problem.
> Since this is a regression in the upcoming v2.23.0 release (for which we're in `-rc0`), let's revert for now and work on a fix separately.
>
> (Note that this isn't a pure revert; the previous commit added a test showing the regression, so we can now flip it to `expect_success`).

Comment: If you happen to know, is this change not in 2.5.1 yet?

Comment: @kkm https://github.com/git/git/commit/4dbe66464b4fd695c5989cc272fa0edd6475037c is in git 2.3.1

Comment: Thanks, then it seems my issue is different. I'll search more and post a separate question if cannot find anything to help resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem in curl, because git in debian was compiled with curl option ANY_AUTH, and when git client try connect to webserver and first ask  it negotiate auth and it can't do it, git don't try basic auth, because basic is lower security than negotiate. When I try curl --anyauth I can' get data from webserver too, but if I change --basic all works fine, problem in that I can't tell git what auth should use.

Comment: is there a workaround?  like a git option or environment variable to force basic?

Answer (score 1):

It's something weird in libcurl, not a problem in Git. There is a workaround. Libcurl doesn't enable any authentication code if you don't pass username and password to the library. This happens if you use negotiate (kerberos) too which doesn't require username and password. The simple solution:

```
echo http://x:x@git.example.com > ~/.git-credentials
git config --global credential.helper store
```

x:x is the username and password. You can use any random string there. It's only needed to enable the code path to authentication in libcurl. Then kerberos will work (works for me :) ).