# Kerberos authentication with Git in TFS2013

Tags: git, kerberos

Previously, with my TFS2012 server, using `git tf`, a Linux user which is logged in using single-sign-on with Kerberos (credentials show up in `klist`) would not have to enter his username or password.

With TFS2013 using Git for source control, any `push`/`fetch` command requires a username and a password. This can be alleviated by modifying the `remote` URL to `http://user:password@server/...`, but that is insecure, and requires updating whenever the password changes. Is there any way to use Kerberos credentials for TFS2013 git HTTP authentication?

Note: As later checked, the username and password are not *required*, just requested. Hitting plain return will cause got to fall back to kerberos authentication, which works. How do I get git to try kerberos *first*?

Comment: You can use an gpg-encrypted `.netrc` file: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309, instead of keeping your password in plain text in your https url.

Comment: Is your TFS2013 server configured to use Kerberos? Or is it in NTLM mode (default)?

Comment: Yes, the server is configured to use kerberos.

Comment: I asked around a bit and this is supposedly default git behavior. It asks so that you can opt to use different credentials.If you supply none,your kerberos credentials are used. TFS isn't doing anything special here, it's Git that's acting 'weird'.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking if there's any way to change this behavior in git.

Comment: That should work better with git 2.8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626443/6309

Answer (score 2):

If *libcurl*, which is used by git for HTTP(S), is supplied with empty credentials, it will happily do Negotiate authentication. When prompted for username and password, just hit Enter twice.

To *save* the empty credential, set your credential helper to the basic store:

`git config --global credential.helper store`

Then on your next interaction with the remote (push, pull, clone, etc) just hit enter twice.

Credit for this answer should go to [diegows](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276950/diegows) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19059201/6970).