# How to force Git (2.5+) HTTP transport prefer SPNEGO over Basic authentication?

Tags: git, libcurl, http-authentication, spnego

**Summary:** I am using Git for Windows 2.5.1 to authenticate with a Kerbesized Git server. When I am using the URL in the form `https://el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git`, Git does not even attempt the Negotiate authentication, and asks for the user name and password. A workarouond to force Git to use SPNEGO is to [provide empty username and password in the URL itself](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-access-a-repository-hosted-on-a-microsoft-team-foundation-server-inside-a-windows-domain), as in `https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git`. In this case, Git happily authenticates with the existing Kerberos ticket.

Can I configure Git to try SPNEGO without tweaking the remote URL?

**More details.** I spent quite a time trying to solve the problem. First I tried [giving an empty user name in .gitconfig](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials), but to no avail:

```
[credential "https://el2-gitlab.sa.c"]
   username = ''
```

Not once I came across questions on a *reverse* problem, when Git refused to revert to Basic after trying and failing Negotiate, but the behavior is [confirmed to have changed in 2.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522956/1149924).

Responding to the prompts with the empty username and password does not help, contrary to some suggestions I could find on SO (but they may pre-date version 2.3.1).

Finally, verbose libcurl output (abridged here) shows that Git indeed attempts Basic authentication and forgoes Negotiate altogether:

```
$ export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
$ git clone https://el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git kerbtest
Cloning into 'kerbtest'...
* Couldn't find host el2-gitlab.sa.c in the _netrc file; using defaults
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> GET /kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: el2-gitlab.sa.c
User-Agent: git/2.5.1.windows.1

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Status: 401 Unauthorized
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
< Www-Authenticate: Negotiate
<
* Connection #0 to host el2-gitlab.sa.c left intact
Username for 'https://el2-gitlab.sa.c':
```

Also may be of interest is that the Git client retries the unauthenticated request on a 401 for the second time before responding with the ticket:

```
$ git clone https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git kerbtest
Cloning into 'kerbtest'...
* Couldn't find host el2-gitlab.sa.c in the _netrc file; using defaults
> GET /kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: el2-gitlab.sa.c
User-Agent: git/2.5.1.windows.1

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Status: 401 Unauthorized
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
< Www-Authenticate: Negotiate
* Connection #0 to host el2-gitlab.sa.c left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host el2-gitlab.sa.c in the _netrc file; using defaults
> GET /kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: el2-gitlab.sa.c
User-Agent: git/2.5.1.windows.1

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Status: 401 Unauthorized
< Www-Authenticate: Basic realm=""
< Www-Authenticate: Negotiate
<
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack'
* Couldn't find host el2-gitlab.sa.c in the _netrc file; using defaults
> GET /kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: el2-gitlab.sa.c
Authorization: Negotiate YIIGtg[ .... trimmed ... ]
User-Agent: git/2.5.1.windows.1

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: Starting with git 2.8+ (March 2016), a simple `git config http.emptyAuth true` should be enough. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35626443/6309)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

git 2.8 (March 2016) should alleviate that issue and **force an empty username and password** during http authentication:

See [commit 121061f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/121061f67fd47aed5b2f3a7deb82af15215636bd) (15 Feb 2016) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 65ba75b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/65ba75ba7daae3298139f18cf866a23d01f4dd48), 24 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `http`: add option to try authentication without username
>
> Performing GSS-Negotiate authentication using Kerberos does not require specifying a username or password, since that information is already
>   included in the ticket itself.
>   However, `libcurl` refuses to perform authentication if it has not been provided with a username and password.
>
> **Add an option, `http.emptyAuth`, that provides `libcurl` with an empty username and password to make it attempt authentication anyway.**

The [`git config` documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/121061f67fd47aed5b2f3a7deb82af15215636bd/Documentation/config.txt#L1603-L1607) will mention:

```
http.emptyAuth:
```

> Attempt authentication without seeking a username or password.
>   This can be used to attempt GSS-Negotiate authentication without specifying a username in the URL, as `libcurl` normally requires a username for authentication.

---

Git 2.10.2 (Octobre 2016) will improve that.

See [commit 5275c30](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5275c3081c2b2c6166a2fc6b253a3acb20f8ae89) (04 Oct 2016) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c6400bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6400bf8d5437e7614c86e6b027761e11ed7a1be), 17 Oct 2016)</sup>

> ### `http: http.emptyauth` should allow empty (not just NULL) usernames
>
> When using Kerberos authentication with newer versions of libcurl,
>   `CURLOPT_USERPWD` must be set to a value, even if it is an empty value.
>   The value is never sent to the server.
>   Previous versions of libcurl did not require this variable to be set.
>   One way that some users express the empty username/password is `http://:@gitserver.example.com`, which `http.emptyauth` was designed to support.
>   **Another, equivalent, URL is `http://@gitserver.example.com`**.
>   The latter leads to a username of zero-length, rather than a `NULL` username, but `CURLOPT_USERPWD` still needs to be set (if `http.emptyauth` is set).
>   Do so.

---

Git 2.13 (Q2 2017) will reduce authentication round-trip over HTTP when the server supports just a single authentication method.

See [commit 40a18fc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40a18fc77ca3ba1b018f0fbdcbdf4a6d237aadf3) (25 Feb 2017), and [commit 840398f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/840398feb85bc0943119c669cda266a876859818) (22 Feb 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
Helped-by: [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 92718f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92718f57c2e18e69bc7ae3ed18c7157c475e17a9), 10 Mar 2017)</sup>

> ### `http`: add an "`auto`" mode for `http.emptyauth`
>
> This variable (`http.emptyauth`) needs to be specified to make some types of non-basic authentication work, but ideally this would just work out of the box for everyone.
>
> However, simply setting it to "`1`" by default introduces an extra round-trip for cases where it *isn't* useful. We end up sending a bogus empty credential that the server rejects.
>
> The "auto" mode should make it work out of the box, without incurring
>   any extra round-trips for people hitting Basic-only servers.

Comment: Changing this one to selected answer status (mine of 2015 is now outdated, fortunately!)

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. Using cURL in plain against the host server worked fine. Just the Git CLI was always falling back to Basic instead of using the Negotiate scheme. That config setting fixed that behavior!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a Git problem but a `curl` one. You are suffering from [known bug #10](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/knownbugs.html). `curl`'s implementation is far below the one of `libserf`which is used in Subversion.

Regarding selection of the auth: Git requests `ANY_AUTH` with `libcurl`and it should select the strongest available mechanism. If it doesn't (with plain `curl`), you have found a bug. Please report to `curl`on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a workaround though that would make Git pass the empty username and password to libcurl, outside of changing the URL? Also, I cannot understand the second paragraph. If this is a known bug, then why should I report it? And how can I try the same thing with plain `curl`?

Comment: Try to clone initially from `https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git`. The second paragraph is about the mixup of auths. Same in curl: `$ curl --negotiate https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git` or to resemble Git's config:  `$ curl --any-auth https://:@el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git`.

Comment: I see. when I do `$ curl -s -v --negotiate https://el2-gitlab.sa.c/kkm/GrammarTools.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack`, curl does not attempt at the auth, as in the bug 10. When I however specify *any* username including an empty one with the `-u ''` switch, then curl simply hangs printing nothing. This does not look like what was reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/440/ -- do you think this is still the same bug?

Comment: You either have to pass the `: ` in the URL or as parameter like `-u :` but not `-u ''`.

Comment: Aha, `-u :` did the trick! Unfortunately, `git config --global credential.https://el2-gitlab.sa.c.username ':'` did not :( Can you think of any way of tricking git into passing curl a fake username, but **without** changing the remote URL?

Comment: Just found that putting the host clause with the fake username and password into `.netrc` (or rather `_netrc` in this Windows port) causes git to attempt Kerberos! This will do it for us. Thanks for the hints!

Comment: @kkm Yes, this is equivalent but ugly. Since this was helpful you might consider accepting and/or upvoting this answer.

Comment: In all fairness to the community, the reply as written does not answer the question. The question was *can I configure Git to try SPNEGO without tweaking the remote URL?* and I believe an accepted answer should, well, answer it. Would you mind augmenting your response with the actual answer: however ugly in your opinion, setting `_netrc` really achieves what the OP wanted. I'll gladly accept it with this modification. (And if you are wondering why I need that, out Git server, GitLab shows the url w/o the `@:` part, and I it's important that users be able to copy/paste the url without change).

Comment: @kkm I understand, please keep in mind that I have depicted the issue in curl. You can raise this again with curl and fix that known issue.

Answer (score 0):

**ATTENTION:** This used to be the selected answer but is now obsolete as of git v2.8. Please scroll to the [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35626443/1149924) which is now checkmarked green.

#### Everything below this line is historical and obsolete. Don't.

---

With most of the [credit going to @Michael-O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788662/1149924) in the discussion under his answer to this question, I believe the final straightforward solution for the problem should be posted in the interest of the SO community.

The workaround to the known bug in libcurl that Michael mentioned is to create a file `~/.netrc` (original libcurl) or `~/_netrc` (Git for Windows 2.5+ port, based on MSys2). The file should provide an empty username and password for the Kerberized Git server host. Since the host matching is exact, include both the short and fully-qualified DNS names and possible aliases if any, for example,

```
machine gitlab.acme.com username '' password ''
machine gitlab          username '' password ''
```

If everything is right, the line that you see in the original question logs

```
* Couldn't find host el2-gitlab.sa.c in the _netrc file; using defaults
```

should no longer be printed, and Negotiation authentication with user's Kerberos ticket should be used.